# Get hierarchical tree from database with minimum number of queries

Tags: c#, sql, tree

Right now I have the following table schema:

`Node_Id (INT)| NodeName (nvarchar(40)) | ParentNode(int, FK)`

I want to retrieve hierarchical tree from that structure: structure simmilar to this one: `{NodeId, NodeName, IEnumerable<Node> Children, bool hasChildren}`

I see two solutions for this problem: first is tree traversal. I mean to load root nodes (where parent=null) and then for each node load it's children and recursively do this for these nodes. But each child load results in additional query to DB which is performance hit.

Another option I see would be to load flat strucure from database (the same as table schema) and then from it build hierarchical structure. That is performance hit to application server.

I was wondering if there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to show all the tree children at once, immediately, you could load based on a specified parent node and then load on demand as the user expands the tree children. This would result in a lighter load on the application and DB servers.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of lazy loading, that is option. However if possible I'd like to avoid it and load tree at once - it's nearly 15000 nodes - not so big enough.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions you already mentioned you also have the possibility to use connect by / start with in oracle sql.

See this link for further infos: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm